# React / useState (complex) - dynamic input fields and fecthed data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-state

I've problems with binding a config object for a list of input fields and fetched data from api. Restore the input changes to useState and restore fetch data from api to useState.

onChange: change the input value in the useState data and show the information in the input field.

onFetch: i get a simple api resonse with key and value. This response should show at the input fields.

```
import React from 'react';

interface InputInterface {
    key: string,
    label: string,
    value: any
}

const input_array: Array<InputInterface> = [
    { key: 'userid', label: 'User ID', value: '' },
    { key: 'firstname', label: 'Firstname', value: '' },
    { key: 'lastname', label: 'Lastname', value: '' },
    { key: 'department', label: 'Department', value: 'NI' },
    { key: 'location', label: 'Location', value: '' }
];

const simulated_fetch: any = {
    userid: 12544,
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    department: 'New York',
    location: 'Brooklyn'
}

export const DynamicForm = () => {

    const [inputlist, setInputlist] = React.useState<Array<InputInterface>>(input_array);

    const onChangeInput = (e: any, key: string) => {
        // setInputlist({      //  something like this
        //     ...inputlist,
        //     [key]: e.target.value
        //});
    }

    const onFetch = () => {
        // setInputlist(simulated_fetch); // something like this
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                {inputlist.map((item: InputInterface, index: number) => (
                    <div key={index}>
                        <label>{item.label}</label>
                        <input value={item.value} onChange={(e) => { onChangeInput(e, item.key) }} />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </form>
            <button onClick={() => { onFetch() }}>Simulate Fetch</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with typescript  but i think this js code help you out ,hope this is what you are looking for .

```
const onChangeInput = (e: any, key: string) => {
const inList = [...inputlist];
inList.forEach((ele)=>{
    ele.key === key ? (ele.value = e.target.value): '';
    })
    setInputlist(inList);
}

const onFetch = () => {
  const inList = [...inputlist];
inList.forEach((ele)=>{
    ele.value = simulated_fetch[ele.key];
    })
    setInputlist(inList);
}
```